# Upload ionic 2 app in ionic view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to upload my ionic tabs application to ionic view, it's get uploaded but the problem is manually created pages are gives error. And it can not detect the changes from that manually created page.

i am using this commands after making changes:

> git add -p
>
> git commit -m 'changed app page'
>
> git push
>
> git push ionic master

Answer (score 0):

You have to run first `ionic upload` then proceed with the commands you did then go to Ionic view and deploy the new version.

**PS:** Ionic view is deprecated since the 31th of January

Comment: but in ionic upload command, there is a message that i need to use legacy backend and as per that i changed legacy but in this backend i am unable to login with my cridential

Comment: its a different login, and like I said its deprecated

Comment: so u mean now I should not use ionic view...?

Comment: From where do you have the information, that Ionic View is deprecated?

Comment: now finally i made it working on ionic view, but still have one question. can i make the http call from the ionic view?

Comment: it depends on how u implemented it, if it post requests to a server then it should work